# Java LocalDate получить дату понедельника и пятницы предыдущей недели

Tags: java, дата

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как, используя LocalDate, получить дату прошлого понедельника - 26.11.2018 и дату предыдущей пятницы - 30.11.2018

И чтобы, запустив в любой день, мы могли получить актуальную дату предыдущего понедельника( и пятницы)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вспомогательный метод [`TemporalAdjusters.previuos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#previous-java.time.DayOfWeek-) можно использовать чтобы получить дату предыдущего понедельника/пятницы:

```
LocalDate previousMonday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
LocalDate previousFriday = LocalDate.now().with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY));
```

Обратите внимание, что этот метод возвращает первую дату с заданным днем недели до исходной. Т.е. если Вы запустите этот метод в субботу или воскресенье, то вернуться понедельник и пятница *текущей* недели.

Если нужно всегда получать дни предыдущей недели, даже если такие дни уже прошли на текущей неделе, то можно использовать метод [`LocalDate.with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) с днем недели:

```
LocalDate mondayOnPreviousWeek = previousFriday.minusWeeks(1).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
LocalDate fridayOnPreviousWeek = previousFriday.minusWeeks(1).with(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY);
```

См. также похожие вопросы на английском:

- [What is the best way to retrieve the dates for last Monday and Friday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661203/what-is-the-best-way-to-retrieve-the-dates-for-last-monday-and-friday/39580958)
- [Get last week date range for a date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210839/get-last-week-date-range-for-a-date-in-java)

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что нужно!)